# how to push new child object inside table of object using angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning Angular.with firebase
and I created produts stored in firebase as

```
product:{
name:"test1",
votes:
  [
  vote:{adressIp:"102.169.235.190",
    nbvote:4}
   ]

}
```

this is my object

```
export  interface vote{
    vote:{
        adresseIp:string;
        nbvote:number;
    }
}
```

And I have a function upstart

```
  upstar(nbvote){
    let userid:string;
    this.MyuserService.getIpAddress().subscribe(
      ip=>{userid=ip.ip  
        const up:vote ={vote:{adresseIp:userid,
          nbvote:nbvote
          }}
          this.itemDoc.update( { votes:[up]}) 
        }
      )
```

I call upstart when user clicked a button

and the role of upstart is push  new child object inside  table of object
in firestore

but My issue is  when to call upstart is going to update 
votes [0].vote.adressIp and votes [0].vote.nbvote
rather to rather to push  new child object inside  table of object

my goal push  new child object inside  table of object when calling upvote  this like

```
product:{
name:"test1",
votes:
  [
  vote:{adressIp:"102.169.235.190",
    nbvote:4}
   ],
  [
  vote:{adressIp:"101.129.233.140",
    nbvote:3}
   ],

}
```

Comment: you cannot have the same name, thats why it overwrites. You should probably increment it, example `vote:{..}` `vote1:{..}`